# How to get the position/index of an ancestor element within the ancestor elements parent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xquery, xquery-sql

I've got xml that looks like this:

```
<items>
    <item>
      <itemproperty>true</itemproperty>
      <details>
        <details>
          <ID Type="z" Value="1"/>
          <ID Type="w" Value="2"/>
        </details>
      </Locations>
    </item>
    <item>
      <itemproperty>true</itemproperty>
      <details>
        <details>
          <ID Type="a" Value="3"/>
          <ID Type="b" Value="4"/>
        </details>
      </Locations>
    </item>
</items>
```

I want to produce output like this:

```
ItemIndex    DetailIDType     DetailIDValue
1            z                1
1            w                2
2            a                3
2            b                4
```

I'm querying from the /items/item/details/detail/ID node and experimenting with trying to figure out the position/index of the ancestor item element.  I can get the total count of item elements, but am struggling to find the position of the item element. In all cases it is not returning the correct index/position value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [TestGetItemElementName] = IDs.id.value('fn:local-name(./../../..)', 'varchar(50)')
    ,[TestGetItemElementCount] = IDs.id.value('count(/items/item)', 'int')
    ,[ItemIndexTest1] = IDs.id.value('for $i in ./../../.. return count(/items/item/*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')
    ,[ItemIndexTest2] = IDs.id.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')

    ,[DetailIDType] = convert(VARCHAR(256), IDs.id.query('data(./@Type)')) 
    ,[DetailIDValue] = convert(VARCHAR(256), IDs.id.query('data(./@Value)'))
FROM 
    @x.nodes('/Recipients/Recipient/Locations/Location/ID') AS IDs(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using the parent axis (`..` or `parent::node()`) in XPath queries as it can be a serious performance killer.

You can achieve what you're looking for by using [DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql) to provide automatic numbering of the `item` nodes with code such as the following...

```sql
declare @x xml = N'<items>
    <item>
      <itemproperty>true</itemproperty>
      <Locations>
        <details>
          <ID Type="z" Value="1"/>
          <ID Type="w" Value="2"/>
        </details>
      </Locations>
    </item>
    <item>
      <itemproperty>true</itemproperty>
      <Locations>
        <details>
          <ID Type="a" Value="3"/>
          <ID Type="b" Value="4"/>
        </details>
      </Locations>
    </item>
</items>';

select
  dense_rank() over (partition by items order by item) as ItemIndex
  ,details.value('@Type', N'nvarchar(256)') as DetailIDType
  ,details.value('@Value', N'nvarchar(256)') as DetailIDValue
from @x.nodes('//items') nodes1(items)
cross apply items.nodes('item') nodes2(item)
cross apply item.nodes('Locations/details/ID') nodes3(details);
```

Which yields the results:

| ItemIndex | DetailIDType | DetailIDValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | z | 1 |
| 1 | w | 2 |
| 2 | a | 3 |
| 2 | b | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

I see you tried to use a **Node Comparison** operator to get the **ItemIndex** column values. Here is how to do it correctly.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @x XML = 
N'<items>
    <item>
      <itemproperty>true</itemproperty>
      <Locations>
        <details>
          <ID Type="z" Value="1"/>
          <ID Type="w" Value="2"/>
        </details>
      </Locations>
    </item>
    <item>
      <itemproperty>true</itemproperty>
      <Locations>
        <details>
          <ID Type="a" Value="3"/>
          <ID Type="b" Value="4"/>
        </details>
      </Locations>
    </item>
</items>';

SELECT c.value('for $i in . return count(/items/item[. << $i])', 'INT') AS ItemIndex
    , c.value('@Type', 'VARCHAR(20)') as DetailIDType
    , c.value('@Value', 'INT') as DetailIDValue
FROM @x.nodes('/items/item/Locations/details/ID') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| ItemIndex | DetailIDType | DetailIDValue |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|         1 | z            |             1 |
|         1 | w            |             2 |
|         2 | a            |             3 |
|         2 | b            |             4 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```